# Why doesn't setting the SUID bit in OpenBSD set effective and saved UIDs to executable file owner?

Tags: permissions, user-permissions, setuid, openbsd, suid

I am using a fresh install of OpenBSD 5.3 as a guest OS on Parallels for Mac:

```
$ uname -a
OpenBSD openbsd.localdomain 5.3 GENERIC#53 amd64
```

To my surprise, a binary file owned by root with its SUID bit set runs with UIDs as if the SUID was not set. That is, when UID 1000 runs such a program, the program starts in state:

```
 <real_uid, effective_uid, saved_uid> = <1000, 1000, 1000>
```

and **not** in state:

```
 <real_uid, effective_uid, saved_uid> = <1000, 0, 0>
```

as expected.

**Why is this the case?**

Here are the details regarding how I found the issue:

I have written an interactive C program (compiled as *setuid_min.bin*) for evaluating setuid behaviour in different Unix systems. The program lives in a subdirectory of UID 1000's home directory, and the *sudo* command is used to change ownership and SUID; then the program is run and I enter the *uid* to report the real, effective, and saved UIDs of the process:

```
$ sudo chown root:staff setuid_min.bin
$ ls -l | grep 'setuid_min\.bin$'
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   staff [...] setuid_min.bin
$ sudo chmod a+s setuid_min.bin
$ ls -l | grep 'setuid_min\.bin$'
-rwsr-sr-x  1 root   staff [...] setuid_min.bin
$ ./setuid_min.bin
uid
 1000 1000 1000 some_pid
exit
$
```

Note that *some_pid* above is the pid of the *setuid_min.bin* process. The program reports the real UID, effective UID, and saved UID by reporting the output of the following shell command:

```
ps -ao ruid,uid,svuid,pid | grep '[ ]my_pid$'
```

where *my_pid* is the pid is reported by *getpid()*. My only guess as to why this might be the case is that OpenBSD has some underlying permissions structure that is using the ownership/permissions of the directory where *setuid_min.bin* resides, or that is not actually changing ownership/SUID bit when an unprivileged user uses *sudo* to change file permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your binary is in one of the default partitions that are mounted "nosuid". The default fstab the install script creates will by mount everything nosuid unless it's known to contain suid binaries.